# Glimpse timeline missing details

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, glimpse

Does anybody know why the timeline in Glimpse would be missing all of the details between the Begin Request and End Request events?

I've made sure I have `debug="true"` in my web.config, but that doesn't seem to help.

Some additional details:

- MVC3 app
- Using Sitecore CMS
- Glimpse version 1.3

I would give more details, but just not sure what is/isn't relevant.

I can't find anybody reporting this same issue, so not sure what could be causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you have installed [Glimpse.MVC3](https://nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.Mvc3) which augments the Timeline tab with information about the MVC3 execution pipeline.